Fetch the container for autofilter dropdown using Javascript for Microsoft office365 Excel
I am trying to click on the dropdown menu for filter options using Javascript. I have set the iframe as WacFrame_Excel0. But I am unable to find the container to click on the dropdown menu. Attaching an image for reference

I have to click on this dropdown to enable different filters present within the dropdown list.
I am able to see <div class="ms-Callout-container container-286" style="visibility: hidden;"> contains all the elements for individual filters within the dropdown.
